# I received a call about my iCloud account and I need to know if it is a scam

Tags: icloud

I just received a call stating my iCloud account has been compromised.  They want me to go on my computer with them.  Is this a scam?

Comment: Yes never ever give any information to   a person you did not call. If someone calls you ask for their company name and then look up a number for that company and call them if there is a reason you know of that that particular company might ring you - never use a number that the caller gives over the phone - anything else is a scam

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will never receive an unexpected call regarding your iCloud account, so it is a scam.

Answer (score 1):

Apple will never call you and ask you to "go on [your] computer with them" to recover a compromised iCloud account (which they would refer to as an Apple ID, not iCloud account).

If you called them about a compromised Apple ID, they use the information you provided at registration and possibly information you email or fax to them (such as driver's license) to verify your identity and reset your account.